# the bits in R to express integer

Tags: r

R use 32-bit integers, 4 bytes (4*8=32, 1 byte=8 bits),max integer is 2^31-1= 2147483647.

```
intToBits(125)
[1] 01 00 01 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

There are 64 bits ,not 32 bits,32 pairs of 00 or 01(32*2=64) ,why?
in the manual ,a raw vector with entries 0 or 1,what is the meaning of entries 0 or 1?

In my opinion, `intToBits(125)` will generate
`10111110 00000000 00000000 00000000`    # it is 32 bits
not
`01 00 01 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`.  # it is 64 bits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function `intToBits` returns 32 numbers, each `0` or `1`.

```
> length(intToBits(125))
[1] 32
```

The confusion is caused by the hex representation of the `raw` type of the output of `intToBits`.

```
> intToBits(125)[3]
[1] 01
```

The `raw` numbers `0` or `1` are shown as `00` or `01`.

Comment: Just an addition to this answer: If you want the binary representation instead of the hex representation, use `as.numeric(intToBits(125))`